# .ENV is not working in razzle js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

im try to deploy a razzle project in a server with Ubuntu.
I'm have created a .env and inside 2 variables port=80 and host=192.168.1.5 (for example)
when i run the project is running in localhost:3000 (default)
I try export PORT=80 and run for this port
But when i try to set the HOST show me an error (Error: Could not find an open port at 192.168.1.5 )
if export 0.0.0.0 not load the client side.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `RAZZLE_PORT` and `RAZZLE_HOST` in a '.env' file located in **root**

Comment: can you please add more details!

Comment: I taste with RAZZLE_PORT and RAZZLE_HOST, and nothing... the right way is using razzle_heroku... thank for the answer